# Finding the newest files in multiple folders and send them to other folder

Tags: python, file, file-management

I have 3 folders (A, B and C) in Source. Each folder contains at least 1 file. I want to find the newest files in each folder and send that to the Destination which also contains folders A, B and C. The NOT-newest files will be moved to Archive, which also contains folders A, B and C. I used the code below, but I get the following error: `NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'c:\\data\\AS\\Desktop\\Source\\A\\12.txt'`

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import shutil, os, os.path
import time

#Make Source, Destination and Archive paths.
source = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\Source'
destination = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\Destination'
archive = r'c:\data\AS\Desktop\Archive'

#First os.walk for the source folder itself
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for folder in dirs:
        subdir=root+'\\'+folder
        #second os.walk for each folder in the source folder (A, B, and C)
        for subroot, subdirs, subfiles in os.walk(subdir):
            for file in subfiles:
                filePath=subroot+'\\'+file
                maxi = max(os.listdir(filePath), key=os.path.getctime)
                print(maxi)
```

I also would like to know what key stands for in key=os.path.getctime. Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is only to move files in sub-directories one level below `source`, then you do not want to use `os.walk()`. That is a recursive walk and will enumerate all directories/files under the root directory. Instead, use `os.listdir()`, which will only list immediate sub-directories and files. Note also that `os.path.getctime()` requires a complete *path* and will not work given only the file name returned by `os.listdir()`.

```
import os
import os.path

src = 'src'
dst = 'dst'
arc = 'arc'

for subdir in os.listdir(src):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(src, subdir)
    if not os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        # Only consider directories (a, b, c, ...) under src; skip files.
        continue

    # Get a list of absolute paths of _files_ in the sub-directory.
    subfile_paths = [os.path.join(subdir_path, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir_path)]
    subfile_paths = [p for p in subfile_paths if os.path.isfile(p)]

    if len(subfile_paths) == 0:
        # Skip empty sub-directories.
        continue

    newest_path = max(subfile_paths, key=os.path.getctime)

    for subfile_path in subfile_paths:
        if subfile_path == newest_path:
            dst_root = dst
        else:
            dst_root = arc

        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_root, subdir, os.path.basename(subfile_path))
        os.rename(subfile_path, dst_path)
```

Comment: now your code actually did exactly what I wanted, thank you for that. But could you please walk me through it? Like for example what is the difference between the both subfile_paths? And I have an other quick one. Right now only the MAX files are getting moved to destination, like if I want to add and other requirement that they have to be the MAX files AND they have to be at least 120 seconds old. I though of adding a os.stat(subfile_paths) and current.time and use >60 / 2? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first `subfile_paths` list comprehension is transforming the list of files in a `subdir` into absolute paths by applying `os.path.join`. The second is filtering out any paths that are not regular files (e.g., there could be a directory in `src/a/`), keeping only those where `os.path.isfile(p) == True`. You could do this in one list comprehension with a redundant call to `os.path.join` or by just using a normal `for` loop.

Comment: If you only wanted to move files into `dst` that are newest _and_ at least 120 seconds old, you can just add another condition: `if subfile_path == newest_path and os.path.getctime(newest_path) < time.time() - 120:`

Comment: Thank you. That worked great. Its 'weird' to see you are able to move files without even using shutil.move. How comes you are not using that one? Like where is the piece of code which actually 'moves' the files?

Comment: `shutil.move` actually calls `os.rename` unless the destination is on a different filesystem. If that's a possibility, you should use `shutil.move` instead. Within the same filesystem, there's no need to actually move the file data.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, but how do I know if the destination is on a different filesystem? English is not my native language...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a result of this line:

```
maxi = max(os.listdir(filePath), key=os.path.getctime)
```

You do not need to do the second os.walk function for folders A, B, and C. When you do this you are assigning a full filepath to the variable filePath. Then when you pass filePath to the max() function it throws the error you are seeing because it is expecting a folder. You should be passing the path to the A, B, and C folders to the max() function, not paths of individual files. You should be able to get rid of the second os.walk structure. Something like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
for folder in dirs:
    subdir=root+'\\'+folder
    maxi = max(os.listdir(subdir), key=os.path.getctime)
    print(maxi)
```

Also, key=os.path.getctime is telling the max() function to use the created timestamp of the file to determine that max. So you are saying show me the maximum file where maximum is defined as the most recent created time.

Comment: Does that mean that key is a keyword known by Python? Because when I change key I get an error.

Comment: yes, it is an optional argument to the max() function - [see this](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/max/)